# "Deux fois plus" signifie-t-il le double ou le triple ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Bonjour, bien que dans le langage commun "deux fois plus" signifie le double, je me dis que ça devrait être interprété comme étant le triple, dans le sens où les deux fois sont en plus de la valeur de départ. Cela est plutôt révélant dans la tournure "4 est une fois plus grand que 4", qui serait correct alors que "4 est zéro fois plus grand que 4" me semble plus cohérent.

Qu'en pensez-vous ? Quelle est la bonne réponse ?

Comment: Quant à « deux fois **moins**, n'en parlons pas ! »

Comment: Cette ambiguité est présente en anglais également, et ce choix de vocabulaire est le sujet d'une question sur matheducators.stackexchange: [Is it meaningful to add a number to itself a fractional number of times?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/26011/is-it-meaningful-to-add-a-number-to-itself-a-fractional-number-of-times/26012#comment67194_26012). C'est aussi une des raison pour lesquelles tend de gens détestent les pourcentages. "Une augmentation de 200%" veut dire "Une multiplication par 3".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dans l'expression *deux fois plus*, « deux fois » indique le rapport entre les mesures et « plus » indique dans quel sens il faut prendre ce rapport, donc 10, c'est deux fois plus que 5.

*Deux fois moins* indique un même rapport de simple au double mais cette fois-ci dans l'autre sens : 5, c'est deux fois moins que 10.

L'expression *une fois plus* (une fois en plus) était en concurrence avec *deux fois plus* jusqu'au début du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle mais ne s'utilise plus aujourd'hui.

Comment: D'accord, merci beaucoup. Donc au final les deux pourraient s'utiliser mais c'est la première qui est conservée.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne suis pas tout à fait d'accord avec la réponse de jlliagre.

Je crois qu'il faut toujours partir du chiffre de départ pour calculer le ratio.

Exemple 1 : J'attendais 5 amis pour un souper mais 10 se sont finalement présentés. Ici nous partons du chiffre 5 pour se rendre à 10, ce qui donne deux fois plus.

Exemple 2 : J'attendais 10 amis pour un souper mais seulement 5 se sont présentés. Ici nous partons du chiffre 10 pour se rendre à 5. Je crois qu'il faudrait dire ici: Il y en a eu "moitié moins" ou "50% en moins" parce que si nous disons "deux fois moins", cela signifierait que -10 amis se sont présentés au souper.

Comment: Dans ton exemple 2, il y a une erreur dans la 1er phrase : "J'attendais 10 amis pour un souper mais 10 " -> "J'attendais 10 amis pour un souper mais 5"

Answer (score 0):

Ne serait-il pas plus simple et sans double interprétation de dire :

> cette maison vaut le double de celle de sa voisine

et

> cette maison vaut la moitié de celle de sa voisine

La langue française est tellement riche et simple à la fois. Pourquoi la compliquer ?

Comment: Ma voisine est à vendre ?