# le mot "augmenter" change-t-il la signification de "X fois plus" ?

Tags: expressions, synonymes, locutions, mathématiques, phrase

Bonjour,

Il me semble qu'avant on utilisait "X fois plus que quelque chose" pour dire X fois plus de cette chose en plus de cette chose (un exemple que je connais est que Dumas Père utilisait "une fois plus" pour dire le double). Mais comme j'ai compris, la langue a changé et que maintenant cela veut dire qu'on prend cette chose là multipliée par X.

Alors si je comprends bien, dans la langue française que nous utilisont maintenant, B est x fois plus petit que A lorsque B*x=A  ou A÷x=B

Mais lorsque les locutions **"fois plus"** et **"fois moins"** sont suivies par les mots **"augmenter"** et **"diminuer"** respectivement, cela change-il la signification?

Par exemple, comment devrais-je comprendre l'idée mathématique dans les phrases suivantes?

***"Entre 1970 et 2002, les dépenses publiques pour la santé ont augmenté 2,3 fois plus que le PIB aux États-Unis, 2 fois plus rapidement [...]"*** --> À mon avis on prendra le nombre de dépenses publiques et on le divisera par 2,3 pour trouver le nombre du PIB. Est-ce cela ?

***"Bien qu'à un niveau bas, les exportations ont augmenté au cours des quelques dernières années dans la période 2001-2004, elles ont augmenté 18 fois."*** --> nombre initial d'exportations multiplié par 18 donne le nombre d'exportations dans la période 2001-2004 ?

***"[...] honnêteté que, entre 1965 et 1994, nos impôts sur le revenu ont augmenté 1 000 fois plus que ceux de la moyenne des pays du G7."*** --> la moyenne d'impôts des pays du G7 multipliée par 1 000 donne "nos impôts" ?

***"Grâce à cet effort, les rendements en blé ont augmenté 40 fois dans son village et toutes les familles ont de nouvelles habitations."*** --> nombre initial des rendements de blé multiplié par 40 ?

Remerciements.

-Eren8hisfather.

Comment: La question me semble sensiblement différente de https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41885/deux-fois-plus-signifie-t-il-le-double-ou-le-triple puisque cette dernière n'aborde pas le problème "*d'augmenter* deux fois plus" qui peut avoir d'autres implications arithmétiques...

Comment: Dans les exemples, le sens exact d'*augmenter* depend du contexte, alors que *plus* ici fait la partie du comparaison (*plus... que...*).

Comment: la formulation "augmenter n fois" pour dire "multiplié par n" est plutôt inhabituelle. N'est-ce pas lié à une traduction depuis l'anglais ou une autre langue ?

Comment: Oui, il aurait été utile de préciser d'où proviennent les phrases qui illustrent la question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salut,

Si Jean a mangé deux patates et Paul une patate, alors

- Jean a mangé deux fois plus de patates que Paul
- Paul a mangé deux fois moins de patates que Jean

C'est donc une multiplication (avec "fois plus") ou une division (avec "fois moins").

> Mais lorsque les locutions "fois plus" et "fois moins" sont suivies par les mots "augmenter" et "diminuer" respectivement, cela change-il la signification?

Non, c'est la même chose, mais dans ce cas l'expression fait référence à ce qu'il y a avant, c'est-à-dire l'augmentation.

Exemple :

Le prix des patates passe de 1€ à 1.10€ le kilo, une augmentation de 0.1€ (10%).

Le prix des cerises passe de 5€ à 6€ le kilo, une augmentation de 1€ (20%).

Dans ce cas tu peux dire "en pourcentage, le prix des cerises a augmenté deux fois plus que celui des patates."

Ou tu peux dire "en euros au kilo, le prix des cerises a augmenté 10 fois plus que celui des patates."

Si il manque l'indication, ce n'est pas clair.

> "Grâce à cet effort, les rendements en blé ont augmenté 40 fois dans son village et toutes les familles ont de nouvelles habitations."

C'est une façon peu claire de dire "rendements blé multiplié par 40".

> nos impôts sur le revenu ont augmenté 1 000 fois plus que ceux de la moyenne des pays du G7.

On ne sait pas si il parle du taux (en %) ou du chiffre total (par exemple en dollars). Supposons qu'il parle en pourcentage: si les impôts dans les pays du G7 ont augmenté de 0.01% alors que ceux de l'orateur ont augmenté de 10%, alors il peut dire "augmenté 1000 fois plus".

> "Entre 1970 et 2002, les dépenses publiques pour la santé ont augmenté 2,3 fois plus que le PIB aux États-Unis

Ici il ne parle pas de "la part de dépenses de santé dans le PIB", mais de montants en monnaie. Par exemple il y a eu une croissance du PIB de 1% mais les dépenses de santé ont augmenté de 2.3%.  Donc les dépenses de santé augmentent 2.3 fois plus vite que le PIB. Ici on ne peut pas en déduire la part exacte des dépenses de santé dans le PIB, mais on sait qu'elle a augmenté.

> "Bien qu'à un niveau bas, les exportations ont augmenté au cours des quelques dernières années dans la période 2001-2004, elles ont augmenté 18 fois."

Il doit parler en nombre d'exportations par an, ou sur une période donnée, sinon on ne peut pas faire de comparaisons. Ça voudrait dire que les exportations par an ont été multipliées par 18 entre 2001 et 2004.

[image]

Une illustration pour répondre à votre question sur le mot "vite" : ici le rouge augmente à peu près deux fois plus vite que le bleu. En anglais on pourrait dire "it increases twice as fast", les deux signifient qu'on ne regarde pas seulement deux valeurs (avant et après) mais plutôt une tendance en fonction d'une variable (ici le temps).

Par exemple, si la voiture rouge va X fois plus vite que la voiture bleue, la distance parcourue par la voiture rouge augmente X fois plus vite que la distance parcourue par la voiture bleue.

Comment: Bonjour, merci pour vôtre réponse. Juste une question, dans vôtre explication (pour le PIB) vous écrivez "les dépenses de santé augmentent 2.3 fois plus vite que le PIB", pourquoi il y a-t-il le mot "vite" ici et que veut-il dire? Et une autre question, si on dit "augmenter x fois plus vite que", cela est different de "augmenter x fois plus que"? Bonne journée.

Comment: Rebonjour, je ne suis pas sûr d'avoir bien compris la partie "si la voiture rouge va X fois plus vite que la voiture bleue la distance parcourue par la voiture rouge augmente X fois plus vite que la distance parcourue par la voiture bleue". Est-ce si la voiture rouge va 6km/h et la bleue 2km/h alors la rouge va 3 fois plus vite que la bleu?

Comment: Et puis, pourrais-je dire que: En km, la distance parcourue par la voiture rouge augmente 3 fois plus (vite) que  la distance parcourue par la bleue? Dois-je mettre "plus vite" ou seulement "plus"? Je suis désolée d'avoir posé trop de question, les maths ne sont pas mon point fort donc ce genre de chose me semble alien.

Comment: ce n'est pas la peine de dire "en km" : la phrase mentionne déjà que c'est une distance, et la proportion est la même quelle que soit l'unité.  Oui pour la question au dessus "3 fois"

Answer (score 3):

1. *"Entre 1970 et 2002, les dépenses publiques pour la santé ont augmenté 2,3 fois plus que le PIB aux États-Unis, 2 fois plus rapidement [...]" --> À mon avis on prendra le nombre de dépenses publiques et on le divisera par 2,3 pour trouver le nombre du PIB. Est-ce cela ?*

- Non, il n'y a pas assez d'éléments pour connaître les valeurs respectives des dépenses de santé et du PIB. En tout état de cause, les dépenses de santé sont forcément largement inférieures au PIB. Il est impossible qu'elles soient 2,3 fois plus élevées que ce dernier puisque les dépenses de santé participent au PIB. Elles financent des services qui sont une partie du PIB d'un pays.

---

2. *"Bien qu'à un niveau bas, les exportations ont augmenté au cours des quelques dernières années dans la période 2001-2004, elles ont augmenté 18 fois." --> nombre initial d'exportations multiplié par 18 donne le nombre d'exportations dans la période 2001-2004 ?*

- La phrase est curieuse, que signifie "les quelques dernières années dans la période 2001-2004" ? D'autre part, on pourrait comprendre "augmenter 18 fois" comme signifiant qu'il y a eu 18 augmentations successives dont on ne connait pas l'intensité. C'est bien sûr plutôt d'une multiplication par dix-huit qu'il s'agit. Attention, il ne s'agit d'un "nombre d'exportations", mesure qui n'a pas beaucoup de sens mais de la valeur de ces exportations (en dollars, euros ou monnaie locale).

---

3. *"[...] honnêteté que, entre 1965 et 1994, nos impôts sur le revenu ont augmenté 1 000 fois plus que ceux de la moyenne des pays du G7." --> la moyenne d'impôts des pays du G7 multipliée par 1 000 donne "nos impôts" ?*

- Non, peut-être que ces impôts étaient 1000 fois moins élevés que ceux de la moyenne du G7 en 1965 et qu'ils ont simplement rattrapé leur retard et sont, en 1994, arrivés au niveau de la moyenne du G7.

---

4. *"Grâce à cet effort, les rendements en blé ont augmenté 40 fois dans son village et toutes les familles ont de nouvelles habitations." --> nombre initial des rendements de blé multiplié par 40 ?*

- Ici aussi, "augmenté 40 fois" peut signifier qu'il y a eu 40 augmentations unitaires mais il faut certainement comprendre ici que les rendements sont 40 fois plus élevés. C'est considérable. Les rendement devaient être très mauvais avant les efforts en question. On est par exemple passé d'un quintal à l'hectare à quarante quintaux.

---

En conclusion :

On ne dit plus *augmenter une fois plus* ou *diminuer une fois plus*, si tant est qu'on l'ait jamais dit.

Les phrases 2 et 4 sont maladroites et fort peu idiomatiques. Il n'y est pas question d'*augmenter x fois plus que* ou *diminuer x fois moins que* mais *augmenter x fois* qui a une autre signification en mathématiques.